# Guardar palavras com acentos python

Tags: python, json, data, codificação-de-caracteres

Tenho este ficheiroo json:

```
{"certa": 1, "vez": 7, "quando": 13, "tinha": 6, "seis": 7, "anos": 6, "vi": 4, "num": 4, "livro": 3, "sobre": 6, "a": 47, "floresta": 1, "virgem": 1, "hist\u00e3\u00b3rias": 1, "vividas": 1, "uma": 31, "imponente": 1, "gravura": 1, ... }
```

Os dados do ficheiro acima são guardados da seguinte forma:

```
    with open(nameFileJson + '.json', 'w') as arq:
        json.dump(data, arq)
```

Onde é dado o nome do ficheiro para a variável `nameFileJson` e `data` é uma string com o texto que será processada para contar o numero de palavras a ser adicionado ao ficheiro json.Ou seja, teremos assim um dicionário de palavras e frequências respetivas. Essa parte faz direito.

Leio o ficheiro json dessa forma:

```
with open(nomeFile + '.json') as json_data:
    dicContadores = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()

return dicContadores
```

Preciso que as palavras continuem a ser guardadas com acentuação. Como resolver isso?

Comment: `with open(nameFileJson + '.json', 'w', encoding='utf8')` não resolve?

Comment: não "fernandoavio. Acabei de testar e deixa igual

Comment: Testou na gravação e na leitura também?

Comment: sim testei também

Comment: "data é uma string com o texto a ser adicionado ao ficheiro json" - não é assim que `json.dump` funciona, ele espera um dicionário e vai despejar todo o conteúdo do dicionário no arquivo, sobreescrevendo se algo estiver escrito (modo `w`). Pode editar sua questão e incluir um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pra vermos exatamente o que você está fazendo e qual é o problema?

Comment: Como foi gerado este JSON? Assumindo que a palavra problemática é "história", o trecho `\u00e3\u00b3` **não corresponde** à letra "ó". O certo seria `\u00c3\u00b3` (assumindo que está em [UTF-8](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-hexadecimal?input=%C3%B3&prefix=false&padding=true&spacing=true))

Comment: Sim, Pedro tem razão. Não expliquei correto já vou dar update

Comment: Está em ANSI @hkotsubo

Comment: Eu quis dizer que se a palavra for "histórias", então o "ó" não deveria estar escrito como `\u00e3\u00b3` (que equivalem aos bytes `e3 b3`). [Fiz um teste](https://ideone.com/TUUk2g) convertendo "ó" p/ vários encodings e o que chega mais perto disso é o UTF-8, que produz `c3 b3` (e não `e3 b3`). Os bytes `e3 b3` podem representar caracteres diferentes em outros encodings ([veja](https://ideone.com/pL0gwk)), mas em nenhum deles representam "ó". Então a string já foi gerada incorretamente na origem, e sem saber como isso aconteceu, não temos como consertar.

Comment: pessoas - a codificação do tipo `\uxxxx` não usa os códigos de UTF-8, e sim, o código dos codepoints de unicode direto. A letra `ó`, num arquivo que não passou por transformações incorretas de codificação, deve aparecer como "\u00f3" (sem nenhuma outra sequência). Os dois últimos dígitos dos codepoints são equivalentes a codificação "latin1".

Comment: A sequência maluca do exemplo  para "ó" acontece se o texto for _passado_ pra utf-8 e em seguida tratado como se estivesse em latin1:
`json.dumps("ó".encode("utf-8").decode("latin1"))` - saída: `'"\\u00c3\\u00b3"'`

Comment: @jsbueno Na pergunta o primeiro byte é `e3`, e não `c3`. Se foi erro de digitação do AP, está explicado. Senão, não sei o que pode ser...

Answer (score 4):

O Módulo JSON do Python codifica texto usando "ensure_ascii" por padrão - isso faz com que todos os caracteres acentuados  sejam codificados na forma `"\uXXXX"`.

Para que as funções do módulo json do Python escrevem as próprias letras em vez de usar essa sequência de escape, basta passar para as mesmas o parâmetro `ensure_ascii=False`.

Ou seja, no seu código, troque

```
json.dump(data, arq)
```

por:

```
json.dump(data, arq, ensure_ascii=False)
```

O texto será gravado na codificação utf-8 (lembre-se que por padrão, programas no ambiente windows podem tentar abrir o texto como se estivesse em latin1 - se os acentos aparecerem de forma incorreta, o melhor a fazer é mudar a configuração desses programas para interpretarem texto como utf-8, e não mexer na codificação utf-8 do JSON, que é padrão para esse tipo de arquivo)

Comment: show, tava com o mesmo problema, usei esse parâmetro e funcionou...